# Error: "You must provide an app access token, or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app" using Facebook Login SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the problem that users can use our system to request reports of their ads on facebook.

These are the functions I use in the frontend (React):

```
export function initFacebookSdk() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // wait for facebook sdk to initialize before starting the react app
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      window.FB.init({
        appId: 'app-id',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v14.0'
      });
      resolve()
    };   
  });
}

export const FbLogin = () => {
  loadFacebookSDK(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk")
  initFacebookSdk()
  return new Promise( resolve => {
    window.FB.login(response => {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        resolve(response);
      } else {
        resolve(response);
      }
    }, {scope: 'ads_management,ads_read'});
  })
}
```

And so I call the function

```
const response = await FbLogin();
```

I send the token to the backend and this is how it uses the route:

```
try {
  const { data: accountsInfo } = await axios({
    url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v${FB_GRAPH_API_VERSION}/me/adaccounts?access_token=${accessToken}&pretty=1&limit=100`,
    method: 'GET',
  });
  

  res.status(200).json({success: true, accountsInfo})
  
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);

  res.status(500).json({success: false})
}
```

And this is the error that I get when trying to use the user token:

```
'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) You must provide an app access token, or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app"'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening to me? help :(

Comment: do you need to wait for `initFacebookSdk()` to run before calling `window.FB.login`? how is `window.fbAsyncInit` triggered? `loadFacebookSDK` looks like it loads a script tag into the document. Do you need to wait for that to load before you run `initFacebookSdk`? does `window.FB.login` always succeed? you don't seem to check for any errors anywhere - `I send the token to the backend` where? have you confirmed that an access token IS being sent??

Comment: The entire part of the flow that corresponds to logging in and obtaining the user's token is resolved, the system receives it correctly. 
The problem is when using the user token to perform queries through graph facebook.

Answer (score 0):

you are not showing how you are sending the token to backend,
and do you really receive it ??
your question need more details ,
and about your way of using the Facebook sdk,
as long as you are using react way you don't use the power of the state and custom hooks to reduce the possibility of the error,
like this :

```js
export const useFacebookSdk = () => {
    const [fcbSdk, setFcbSdk] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {


            FB.init({
                appId: 'app-id',
                autoLogAppEvents: true,
                cookie: true, xfbml: true,
                version: 'v14.0', status: true,
            });


            setFcbSdk((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                login: () => ((scope) => FB.login((r, handleLoginRes) => handleLoginRes(r), { scope })),
                logout: () => (() => { FB.logout() }),
                FcbApiReq: ((path, method, params, cb) => FB.api(path, method, params, cb)),
                getLoginStatus: (() => {
                    let status;
                    FB.getLoginStatus(e => { return status = e })
                    return status
                }),
            }))
        }
    }, [])
    return { ...fcbSdk }
}

// use it like this 
// import { login, logout, FcbApiReq, getLoginStatus} from "./pathOfFile.js"
// or if it s in the same file 
// { login, logout, FcbApiReq, getLoginStatus} =useFacebookSdk()
```

Good luck